# Getting (motorcycle) driver's license as a foreigner in Japan?

Tags: driving-license, indian-citizens, japan, driving

I am Indian have International Driving Permit (IDP) which is valid only for one year (8 months remaining).I would like to know about procedure of getting a motorcycle license in JAPAN. I will live here for 3 more years.

I searched over internet sites like Gajinpot etc. But didn't get a procedure for my situation (that is with IDP, staying for long term). Do I need to take some test? If so, can I take it in English?

Answer (score 3):

After your IDP is no longer valid, you will need to get a Japanese license.

The written test for cars may be taken in English. For cars, the driving (practical) test is conducted in Japanese.

I don't know how they'll administer the tests for a motorcycle license...but the practical test is rigorous. Because there are far fewer applicants for motorcycle licenses than for car licenses, the motorcycle exams will probably be administered in Japanese.

Comment: OP can get a scooter (less than 50cc) license which only requires a written test.